# How to restrict customer event while placing the order in magento

Tags: magento-enterprise, event-observer, customer, php-5.4

In my custom module `customer_save_after` and `customer_address_save_after` are there.

when placing the order `customer_save_after` and `customer_address_save_after` these two events firing.

What is the relation between `sales_order_save_after` and `customer_save_after`, `customer_address_save_after`?

how to restrict `customer_save_after` and `customer_address_save_after` events when place the order?

> I think customer & customer address events are firing because shipping
>   address or billing addresses are Create/updating is happening.

How to restrict customer event from my custom module while placing the order?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by 'restrict'

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `customer_address_save_after` and `customer_save_after_events` are firing while an order is creating.

Address related informations of an order will fire following two events.

1. sales_quote_address_save_after
2. sales_order_address_save_after

`customer_save_after` event is firing when a new customer is created. When we careate an order, I am not sure a new customer is creating for an order. (most probably it is not going to happen).

So the answer to your question is, **there is no relation** between `sales_order_save_after` and  `customer_save_after`, `customer_address_save_after`.

So first make sure that those customer related events are firing while an order is creating in your system. If you are damn sure those events are firing, then you can put this filtering in your observer (ie in `customer_save_after` and `customer_address_save_after`).

```
if (Mage::app()->getRequest()->getRequestedRouteName() == 'customer') {

     //do your magic here
}
```

Above `if` condition makes sure the action is triggering from the route `customer` and hence it will fire only when a customer related actions are carried out.

Answer (score 0):

Set a flag into customer like:

```
Mage('customer/session')->getCustomer()->setMyFlagRestrict(true);
```

in onepage checkout actions.

And rewrite every Observer class that does something with this event.
You'd need to find all observers in `config.xml` files. You can easily use grep command for this.
There is preDispatch in `Mage_Checkout_OnepageController` which could be rewritten and set your flag to `true`.

Comment: setMyFlagRestrict is customer attribute or ?

Comment: It isn't an attribute. It's a simple key/value.